# $n$th derivative of $(x^2-1)^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

> Define $R_n(x)=\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$. Show that $R_n(x)$ is orthogonal to $1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}$ in $L^2([-1,1])$. Also, what is the value of $R_n(1)$?

By definition we have to show that $$\int_{-1}^1R_n(x)x^k=0$$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. This looks a lot like integration by parts, so suppose $S_k$ is the $k$-th derivative of $(x^2-1)^n$. Then

$$\int_{-1}^1R_n(x)x^k=x^kS_{n-1}(x)\mid_{-1}^1-k\int_{-1}^1x^{k-1}S_{n-1}(x)$$.

It looks like the second term can be integrated by parts again, but what is the first term?

Also, how would it be possible to compute $R_n(1)$?

Comment: Hint: $(x^2-1)^n$ has $n$-th order zeros at $x=1$ and $x=-1$.
What does this tell you about its derivatives?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies So the $i$th order derivative must be zero at $-1$ and $1$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. That should solve the first part. What about the second part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Leibnitz Rule

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x-1)^n(x+1)^n= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left( \dfrac{d^k}{dx^k}(x-1)^n \right) \left(\dfrac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}(x+1)^n\right)$$

Now, to evaluate $R_n(1)$, just observe that for $0 \leq k \leq n-1$ the term $\left( \dfrac{d^k}{dx^k}(x-1)^k \right)$ still contains an $x-1$. Thus

$$R_n(1)=\left( \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x-1)^n \right) (x+1)^n |_{x=1}=n!2^n$$

P.S. The above also Yields:

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x-1)^n(x+1)^n= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left( \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}(x-1)^{n-k} \right) \left(\dfrac{n!}{k!}(x+1)^{k}\right) \\= \sum_{k=0}^n   n!  \binom{n}{k}^2(x-1)^{n-k}(x+1)^{k} $$

Comment: Why $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x-1)^n={\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(x-1)^{n-k}}$? Isn't it supposed to be just $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x-1)^n=k!\cdot(x-1)^{n-k}$?

Comment: @GentiSaliu Check your formula when k is 1, or 2 ;)

Comment: Oh my, I overlooked that. Thank you!

Comment: @N.S. can we show $\frac{d^2n}{dx^2n}(x^2-1)^n=2n!$ via using Leibnitz rule and binomials. I’ve tried but I couldn’t find. If yes could you please write it? I have a question about it. Could you please answer there? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

This can be differentiated via Lebnitz rule, 
$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}((x^2 - 1)^{n-1} (x^2 - 1)) = (x^2 - 1)D^{n-1} (x^2 - 1)^{n-1} -2x \binom{n-1}{1}  D^{n-2} (x^2 - 1)^{n-1} - 2 \binom{n-1}{3}  D^{n-3} (x^2 - 1)^{n-1}$$

The first term is zero. The second term and third term can be evaluated in same way such the order of differentiation decreases and decreases until we get zero so we can argue that $D^k(x^2 - 1)^n$ is zero at $x=\pm 1$ if $k<n$.

To find out, $R_n(1)$, we expand binomially and then differentiate, also using the [Rodrigue's formula](http://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node4.html) for Legendre's polynomial, 
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$
we can evaluate this. as $P_n(1) 2^n n!$

Comment: I agree. The other question remains -- how to compute $R_n(1)$.

Comment: @PJMiller can't we use Binomial theorem?? i think it gives $D^n (x^2 - 1)^n = D^n \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} x^{2n - 2k } =\sum_{k=0 }^{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}  \frac{\Gamma(2n - 2k)}{\Gamma(n - 2k)} $